# Communication failure detected when attempting to perform read query outside of a transaction. Attempting to retry query

Tags: jdbc, tcp, eclipselink, derby, entitymanager

I'm running a web server with jetty 9.4.7.v20170914 and connecting to a database using Apache Derby 10.14.1.0. Most of my transactions work fine, but when the database is during heavy load the queries start to fail, hanging up the database until they are successfully completed. I'm running a script that crawls a website and batch inserts thousands of objects in the database and this issue is causing it to take a huge amount of time to complete.

Unit tests work fine for every database operation and I've checked my EntityManager usage to assure that I'm correctly opening, commiting, and closing the transactions. I've tried other versions of Eclipselink, Jetty and Derby, but it didn't solve the issue.

The problem occurs in different queries but I believe it always happens in SELECT statements. Please note that I'm checking if objects exists before creating them, but they are two separate transactions.

```
[EL Info]: query: 2018-06-13 16:03:48.344--UnitOfWork(1800307564)--Communication failure detected when attempting to perform read query outside of a transaction. Attempting to retry query. Error was: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.5.v20170607-b3d05bd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: java.net.BindException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1,527 with message Address already in use: connect.
Error Code: 40000
Call: SELECT t1.ID, t1.PARENTADDITIVECLASSID FROM ADDITIVE t0, ADDITIVE_ADDITIVECLASS t2, ADDITIVECLASS t1 WHERE ((t0.ID = ?) AND ((t2.additiveClasses_ID = t1.ID) AND (t0.ID = t2.additives_ID)))
        bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="entity.Additive.GET_ADDITIVECLASSES" referenceClass=AdditiveClass sql="SELECT t1.ID, t1.PARENTADDITIVECLASSID FROM ADDITIVE t0, ADDITIVE_ADDITIVECLASS t2, ADDITIVECLASS t1 WHERE ((t0.ID = ?) AND ((t2.additiveClasses_ID = t1.ID) AND (t0.ID = t2.additives_ID)))").
```

I also get the following exceptions, although not nearly as frequently.

https://pastebin.com/DWzdhejz

and

https://pastebin.com/0NZ8keF9

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace. The error seems to suggest you are allocating too many sockets, which could mean you aren't correctly closing connections, or should be using a connection pool library.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel That's the only output I get for that specific exception. I sometimes get other errors, but only when during heavy load. I've added them to the post.

Comment: What operating system are you on? Use a tool like 'lsof' or 'netstat' on Linux/Mac, or use a tool like ProcessExplorer on Windows, to see if you can investigate @MarkRotteveel 's idea.

Comment: @BryanPendleton I've tried inspecting this with ProcessExplorer but I don't really know what I'm looking for. The Derby process has one TCP connection always listening and the most connections I've had were two more, in an established state.

Comment: Please post the exceptions inline, don't use pastebin.

Comment: You mention this happens under load and that your database starts to slow down, but have you looked at the traffic on your DB and its processing to try tuning it and your applications usage?  If you are hitting port issues, first thing to check is that you have limited the size of the connection pools to your database to something reasonable for the system. Next is that you have tuned your queries to be ID or indexed queries rather than require table scans interfering with your batch processing. Once the db starts to slow, apps using it will bottleneck on it making things worse.

Comment: You also didn't mention the server you are running on, but the underlying "java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect" message you are getting might be OS related.  See https://www.baselogic.com/2011/11/23/solved-java-net-bindexception-address-use-connect-issue-windows/ and check your pooling settings as the error stack shows it is trying to get a new connection - they should probably be obtained up front and pooled, not created/released under load.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the answer. The server is jetty 9. Tomorrow I will try those steps or maybe even set up a dev environment on Ubuntu. I will report here later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is gone after migrating the database to a native Ubuntu 18.04 installation (running the same image on VMware Workstation 14 didn't solve the issue). As @Chris pointed out in the comments, this is likely a problem with how Windows allocates outbound TCP ports. I'm okay with using Linux for this, but if anyone runs into these issues on Windows be sure to check [this guide](https://www.baselogic.com/2011/11/23/solved-java-net-bindexception-address-use-connect-issue-windows/). Please note that I haven't tested those steps myself.